# can anyone please tell me whats wrong with my session?

Tags: php, session

I'm trying to add an announcement with the need of the user [ id] who posted it and I was going to take it via session I don't know its not working I keep getting this error (Fatal error: Cannot redeclare check_login() (previously declared in C:\xamppp2\htdocs\session.php:17) )

and I'm trying to insert current time and date separately is (date(),now()) are the right functions? I'm trying to insert those too, could you guys possibly help? here's my code

I included the session on top of my page

```
 <?PHP include('session.php');?>
```

and here's the rest of my php file

```
    <?PHP 
    $link = mysql_connect('localhost','root','');

     if (!$link) {
     die('Could not connect :' . mysql_error());
       }

   $Selected= mysql_select_db("elearningg", $link);

    if (!$Selected) {
     die("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());
     }

     if(!empty($_POST))
     {
   $msg = '';
   $error = '';
      $title = $_POST['title'];
      $desc = $_POST['desc'];
      if(trim($title)  == '')
        {$error = 'Please enter event title';}
      else if(trim($desc)  == '')
         {$error = 'Please enter description  ';}
      $IID =$_SESSION['userid']; 
      if($error=='') {
         $qry6="INSERT INTO announcement (`Atitle`,`Adescription`,`Adate`,`Atime`,`IID`) VALUES
         ('$title','$desc',date(),now(),$IID)" ;
           $result6=mysql_query($qry6);
           $msg = " Announcement is added ";
      }
    }
    mysql_close($link);
?>
```

and here's my actual session script..

```
  if (!$link) {
  die('Could not connect :' . mysql_error());
   }

   $Selected= mysql_select_db("elearningg", $link);

   if (!$Selected) {
   die("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());
   }

   ob_start();
   session_start();
   function check_login(){
    if(!empty($_SESSION['userid'])){
    return 1;
    }else{
    return 0;
    }
    }
     ?>
```

Comment: The error message is very clear: you're trying to define the `check_login` function multiple times. Is it in an include file? Use `require_once()` instead of `require()` to prevent loading it multiple times.

Comment: I know this is non-related to your answer, but try to avoid the use of mysql_*, it's better to use mysqli_* or PDO.

Comment: use session_start(); on first line of file...

Comment: i'm using this at first line <?PHP include('session.php');?>

Comment: is it wrong to include it? i already started the session in my included file

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a session problem. You are as your error message says trying to redeclare `check_login()`.

You can only declare a function once.

So depending on how your files are structured you need to make sure that that function is only declared once. Perhaps you use includes in your files. You either need to make sure it isn't redeclared so think about how you structure it so that doesn't happen or use `require_once`, this adds more overhead to your script though.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php

Comment: i'm sorry where can i add this exactly can you show me in which script exactly and where?

Comment: @noura is `check_login()` in a separate file that you include? Is it inside session.php? If so then `require_once('session.php')`